Export txt files from a corpus after preprocessing
I am struggling to export files from my corpus after preprocessing, I currently have 26 documents in my corpus, but i want to export them as txt files os they have been pre processed so i can combine them into one txt file and carry out analysis on vosviewer. How can i do this?
this is the code i have currently:
library(tm)
library(NLP)
cname <- file.path("C:", "TextMining")
cname
docs <- VCorpus(DirSource(cname))
docs
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, tolower)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("arup","may","can","allow","will","use"))
library(SnowballC)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- tm_map(docs, PlainTextDocument)

I wish to now export the txt files now that they have been pre processed and obselete data removed, how could i do this?

According to this post you need the function writeCorpus, which writes txt files using the documents in you corpus.
writeCorpus(docs , path = "output_path/")

Note that the argument filenames is not set. That means the meta tag id in the corpus will be used. You can check the meta tag executing
docs[[1]]$meta$id

